# maven debugging in Vagrant - HADOOP YARN application

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have installed Vagrant as a VM (single node) from [this repository](https://github.com/Cascading/vagrant-cascading-hadoop-cluster/tree/2.5/single-node) and then I installed maven inside so that I can create easily my HADOOP YARN jar files. When I am trying to build my jar `mvn package` I am getting an error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project YarnTestClient: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /vagrant/openlab_ship_proto/YARN/src/main/java/ru/yandex/cern/yarntest/NMCallbackHandler.java:[16,25] generics are not supported in -source 1.3
[ERROR] (use -source 5 or higher to enable generics)
```

I have searched the whole internet but nothing solved my problem. Had anyone faced the same problem before? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this snippet to your pom.xml, if build tag didn't exist in pom.xml, maven would build java with source 1.3

```
    <build>
            <plugins>
                <!-- compiler plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                        <encoding>${project-sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </build>
```